# Visual Studio Team Services REST - Filter Changesets within a project only

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I trying to use the Visual Studio Team Services REST api to retrieve a list of changesets for my project. I am using the following uri:

```
https://<account>.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_apis/tfvc/changesets
```

While the above allows me to get a list of changesets for the entire *project collection* I am unable figure out how to filter them out for a particular *project*. That is, retrieve all the changesets within a particular project only.

The VSTS documentation [here](http://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/reference/reference-vso-version-control-changesets-vsi#Getlistofchangesets) does not provide an example to filter by a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `searchCriteria.itemPath` parameter? E.g.

`https://<account>.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_apis/tfvc/changesets?searchCriteria.itemPath=$/<project name>`

will only list changesets within a project